# Formulario en IOS

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, objective-c, swift3

Estoy haciendo una app en `swift` y necesito hacer un formulario como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio lo estaba haciendo con un `UITableVIew`, pero a la hora de escribir, cuando se desplegaba el teclado me hacie scroll y no se veia el campo.

También he utilizado alguna libreria pero no se puede hacer como en la foto, bien porque no se puede hacer un image picker o por la forma de las cajas...

Alguna solución para poder hacer algo similar??

Comment: LA opción de la tabla la veo buena, lo único que deberías impedir el scroll, o cambiar el tamaño de la celda cuando la toquen  para que se vea. El plan B seria hacer un uitextfield por cada campo que quieras preguntar y hacerlo todo a mano, metido en un scrollview y que se vaya desplazando cada vez que untextfield es firstresponder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías hacerlo como planteaste inicialmente y para solucionar el tema de que el teclado te ocultaba el campo podrías utilizar el pod: "IQKeyboardManagerSwift" , el cual va a mover la vista al seleccionar un campo.

Link pod: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/4.0.2/

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más directo sería usar `UITextField` con el borde de estilo vacío (la primera opción que te muestran en el *interface builder*) y fondo transparente. Luego pones cada `UITextField` dentro de un `UIView` al que le pones fondo color blanco.

Para manejar el movimiento del teclado puedes añadir un *observer* al `NSNotificationCenter` que detecte `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

Todos los `UIView` deben estar dentro de un `UIView` que cubra toda la página y esta debe estar dentro de un `UIScrollView`, el cual permitirá el movimiento de la vista hacia arriba y hacia abajo cuando aparezca y desaparezca el teclado, respectivamente.

Luego, hace que todos los `UITextField` tengan como *delegate* al *controller* que estás usando para mostrar estos elementos; Dicho *controller* debe implementar los métodos del `UITextFieldDelegate` y `UITextViewDelegate` (este último en caso de que también quieras usar algún `UITextView`).

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _activeField = nil;
}
```

Y finalmente haces lo que muestran en este link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215423/1839581

Básicamente muestran los cálculos hechos para mover el `UIScrollView` al detectarse la notificación del teclado, basándose en qué `UITextField` está siendo usado (la variable `_activeField`).